# Object Variable or with block variable not set with find function

Tags: excel, vba

At the moment I have the following piece of code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Search1 as Long

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

Search1 = Range("J:J").Find(What:="HELLO", After:=Range("J1")).Row

end sub
```

but when it gets to the line

```
Search1 = Range("J:J").Find(what:="HELLO", After:=Range("J1")).Row
```

an error message saying

> "Object Variable or with block variable not set"

I don't know why that is happening, I have used this command a thousand times and it has never given me this error

An extra note: this code runs after filling some information in an userform

Comment: Is it because "HELLO" is not found? `Find` will return `Nothing` if it's not found, and `Nothing` cannot be stored in an `Long` variable. Maybe try `Dim Search1 as Variant`

Comment: Where is the command button located?

Comment: Yes, that was the issue, isn't there a way to then say "if Search1 is empty do this... otherwise do that..."? or does it always have to find something to work?

Comment: @vbasic2008 There is a button on Sheet1, that button will display a userform and the userform contains another button (CommandButton1) which will then run that code that I am showing in there

Comment: read the documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find

Answer (score 0):

### A Find Method Issue

**A Quick Fix**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("J:J").Find(What:="HELLO")

    Dim Search1 As Long
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Search1 = rng.Row
    Else
        MsgBox "Not found"
    End If

End Sub
```

- For searching for a value in a column range you are missing two important
  parameters for the arguments `LookIn` and `LookAt` (see
  [Range.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)).
- Keep in mind that your search will start searching in cell `J2`
  (skipping cell `J1`) with or without using `"J1"` as the parameter for the `After` argument.

**An Improvement**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Const SheetName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const findColumn As String = "J"

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Columns(findColumn).Find(What:="HELLO", _
      After:=ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, findColumn), _
      LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    Dim Search1 As Long
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Search1 = rng.Row
    Else
        MsgBox "Not found"
    End If
    ' Possibly continue with e.g.:
    If Search1 > 0 then

    End If

End Sub
```